# Putnam A1 2017 Solution Understanding with congruencies?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

[image: Question]

[image: Solution]

The question and solution are pasted above.

I understand how having n means we can have n+5. After that, I didn't understand anything.

1. What was the logic behind obtaining $54^{2}$?
2. Why do we want a > 1 be an integer that is not a multiple of 5?
3. Where did the sequence $a, a^{2}, \ldots$ come from?
4. I don't understand the relationship between $a$ and the power of 4? Why do we care about that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please take the time to typeset the question/solution; consider also paring down your questions to one or two, as that will make it easier to answer.

Comment: (1) They are just trying to get to a number that is in $S$ and leaves remainder $1$ after division by $5$. By the first observation then all such numbers larger than the one found are also in $S$. This will be useful for (2). (2) They are about to prove that such an $a$ is in $S$. (2) Remember Fermat's little theorem applied to the prime number $5$. It says that if $5\not| a$, then $a^{4}=a^{5-1}\equiv 1\pmod{5}$. The full sequence $a,a^2,a^4,a^8,...$ is not needed, but they are presenting it in a way that also allows reasoning without knowing Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) is Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @Boxwood but aren't there other cases where a number is not divisible by 5? For example, $2 \pmod{5}, 3 \pmod{5}, 4 \pmod{5}$. I understand that $a^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$. Isn't that redundant since we already found that $54^{2}$ creates the equivalence class $[1]$

Comment: Yes, but their argument doesn't require to analyze those cases separately, since Fermat's little theorem allows them to give a single argument for any $a>1$ that is not divisible by $5$. Note that the argument could go like this: Take $a>1$ not divisible by $5$. By Fermat's theorem $a^4$ gives remainder $1$. Therefore, $a^4\in S$. Then using (b) we get that $a\in S$.

Comment: @Boxwood How can we determine that the numbers that are congruent to 1 (mod 5) less than 54^2 exist? We only know that if n exists, then n + 5 exists, so we can inductively construct all the numbers greater than 54^2 in steps of 5. How can we do the same in the opposite direction? 

How do we know 1 is not in the set S? How can we be confident that only the multiples of 5 and 1 are the only elements not in the set S? What if there are others?

Comment: Yes, in their argument they haven't proven yet that the number $\equiv1\pmod{5}$ between $54^2$ and $1$ are in $S$. That is why they need to keep squaring $a^4$ to make it larger than $54^2$ and find an $a^{2^n}\in S$. Note, however, that if you really wanted, with a bit of computation you can deduce that $6\in S$.

Comment: That $1\notin S$ is forced only by $S$ being minimal. They show (well, they say "it is easy to check") that $\{n>1:\ 5\not| n\}\subset S$ and satisfies the properties. Since $S$ is the smallest, then this inclusion is an equality.

Comment: The solution could have been: $2\in S$ implies $49\in S$, implies $54^2\in S$, implies $6^{2^3}=54^2+5\cdot 335340\in S$. Therefore, by (b) $6^4\in S$. By (b) again $6^2\in S$. And finally $6\in S$. Then all $x>1$ with $x\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ are in $S$. Now take $a>1$ with $5\not|a$. Then by Fermat $a^4\equiv1\pmod{5}$. So, $a^4\in S$. By (b) $a^2\in S$ and by (b) again $a\in S$. It is just more computation.

Comment: Please change the tag from 'number-theory' to 'elementary-number-theory'

Comment: @Boxwood I don't understand how finding a number larger than $54^{2}$ helps us find the numbers congruent to 1 that are less than $54^{2}$.

Can you elaborate on what you mean by "this inclusion is an equality"? But just because S is the smallest dosen't mean that we can strip away all elements we are not sure of? For example, just because we don't know that 1 isn't in S, dosen't mean we can just allocate it to S complement. 

What is the point of establishing $6^{4}$? What does it help us with? Also, because 5 dosen't divide 1, can't we say that it is in S?

Comment: (b) allows you to deduce that smaller numbers are in $S$ once you find some larger number in $S$. The larger number just needs to be a square. Anyway, all the explanations that you need has been given to you. You just need to review it and go over the steps. See how if you find a set of numbers that is forced to be inside $S$ and that also satisfies the conditions needs to be all of $S$, if $S$ is supposed to be as small as possible. This is a small deduction that if you are not able to do, then Putnam is not for you yet.

Comment: ok awesome, thanks for the help - I'll focus on doing easier problems first.

Answer (score 0):

We have $54^2 = (55 - 1)(55 - 1) = (55^2 - 2 \cdot 55) + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$; if you are unfamiliar with modular arithmetic, this notation $54^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ means that $54^2$ is $1$ greater than some multiple of $5$, i.e. $54^2 = 5k + 1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since you said "congruencies," you probably know this though. Now that we know $54^2 \in S$, we have $54^2 + 5 \in S$, $(54^2 + 5) + 5 \in S$, and by adding $5$ as many times as we want, we establish that all numbers $\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ greater than $54^2$ are in $S$, so the logic behind obtaining $54^2$ is to show that $n \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ implies $n \in S$ when the number $n$ is large enough, which is useful later.

In the next step, we are showing that $a>1$ and $a$ not a multiple of $5$ implies $a \in S$. By repeatedly taking squares, we get the sequence $a,a^2,a^4,a^8,...$, and Fermat's little theorem says that $a^4 = a^{5-1} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ when $a$ is not divisible by the prime $5$. When a number $\alpha$ has $\alpha \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, we can express $\alpha = 5k + 1$, and then $\alpha^2 = 5(5k^2 + 2k) + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, so when we keep squaring past $a^4$, all the numbers we get are $\equiv 1 \pmod 5$, and eventually we reach a term large enough that $a^n > 54^2$, so $a^n \in S$. Now, condition (b) implies that when a term in the sequence is in $S$, each previous term is in $s$, so $a \in S$ when $a>1$ and $a$ is not a multiple of $5$.

Comment: I understand how $54^{2}$ is congruent to $1 \pmod{5}$. It just seems that $54$ is an arbitrary number, so I my question was - what about the problem made them use/find $54$.

I don't understand why you are trying to get a term large enough such that $a^{n} \gt 54^{2}$. What's the point of that. Also, $a \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ isn't the only way for a number to not be divisible by 5. 2, 3, and 4 are also valid options. Also, you didn't explain why $1$ isn't in $S$.

Comment: @NeelSandell It is not an $a^n>54^2$. It is an $a^{2^n}>54^2$. Note that property (b) allows us to remove squares and $a^{2^n}$ is $a$ squared many times. The relevant of $54^2$ is nothing else than being a number easy to get as being inside $S$ and that is congruent to $1$ modulo $5$. What is important is not the $54$, but the $1$ in the remainders. The $1$ is crucial, because you can always (as long as $5$ doesn't divide your number) get to it using Fermat and squaring.

Comment: @Boxwood Yes I meant an $a^n$ in the sequence, i.e. $n$ is a power of $2$. Apologies, I edited to specify $a > 1$. Our goal is to show that when $a > 1$ and is not a multiple of $5$, $a \in S$. Obtaining $54^2$ gave us a number in $S$ such that all numbers greater than $54^2$ that are $1 \pmod 5$ are in $S$. We want this condition because now, for $a >1$, $a \not\mid 5$, squaring $a$ repeatedly gives us a number in $S$, so then applying condition (b) means $a \in S$ for all such $a$. One can show that $\{a : a>1, a \not\mid 5\}$ satisfies the conditions for $S$, so this is the set $S$.

Comment: *Correction: Prev. comment should state $5 \not\mid a$ instead of $a \not\mid 5$. This notation $5 \not\mid a$ means $a$ is not divisible by $5$.

Comment: Why can't a be greater than or equal to 1?

Comment: Well, our method is to first to show that $54^2 +5k \in S$ for any positive integer $k$, and then when $a$ is a positive integer such that $a > 1$ and $5 \not\mid a$, squaring $a$ repeatedly eventually gives a number in the form $54^2 + 5k$ (equivalently, $a^{2^n} \geq 54^2$ and $a^{2^n} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$), from which by condition (b), $a$ must be in $S$. $a=1$ needs not be in $S$ because $1$ is the only positive integer that doesn't grow without bound when you square it; $1^{2^n} = 1$ for every $n$. $1$ is not in $S$ simply because it doesn't need to be in $S$ for the conditions to hold.